# i want whenever we will entry url extension .php at time page redirect to 404 page?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.] )$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

this is my .htaccess file , this is working properly for remove .php extension , but  i want whenever we will entry url extension .php at time page redirect to 404 page ?

Comment: Can you explain _but i want whenever we will entry url extension .php at time page redirect to 404 page ?_? The sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think what he is saying is that he doesn't want the .php extension, but when they do that, it shows a 404 page?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule [a-zA-Z0-9_.-].php /your404page.html [NC, L]
```

Comment: What if a page has `-` or an extra `.` in the URL?